# C++20 binary semaphore goes over max

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, semaphore, binary-semaphore

I don't understand the difference between counting semaphore and binary semaphore in C++20 (or there's a bug). I can understand the idea, but they both work the same, no difference. I can release the binary semaphore multiple times, then acquire multiple times and it doesn't block (despite that returned max value is 1).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::binary_semaphore sem{0};
    std::cout << sem.max() << std::endl;
    
    sem.release();
    sem.release();
    
    sem.acquire();
    sem.acquire();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:
`g++-11 -O0 -std=c++20 bin_semaphore.cpp -o sem.out`

Out:
`1` and returned.

I assume it should lock forever, but it doesn't. Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semaphores, like much of C++, are not *safe* objects. In particular, nothing will error out just because you released the semaphore more times than its maximum counter value. That merely yields undefined behavior, so you can't do it, but nothing in the API is going to stop you.

The behavior of your code became undefined when you `release`d the semaphore more than its maximum counter variable. What happens next is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok. So, is the `max()` value there just for the "deep mental purpose"? There are no mechanics behind that max value and behind the concept of a "binary semaphore" vs "counting semaphore"? Sounds pompous.

Moreover, not having an access to the current counter state, doesn't even let you make any use of the max value.

Comment: @DeZee: "*There are no mechanics behind that max value*" There are mechanics: you get *undefined behavior* if you exceed it. That's not "pompous"; that's how C++ works. C++ isn't a safe language. "*Moreover, not having an access to the current counter state, doesn't even let you make any use of the max value.*" It's a compile-time constant; you know what the maximum is because it's built into the very *type* of the object. You are expected to know what you're doing with the type, and if you don't, you will get UB. It's not a safe type, as safety has performance costs.

Comment: It still can't convince me - for me the max() is useless. Btw. can't even find in cpp reference that over-releasing results in UB. However, thank you for explaining the concept. At least I know that it doesn't work as I would like to. _"It's not a safe type, as safety has performance costs."_ - yeah, I agree here, but better not to pretend that binary semaphores exist - for me it's just a counting semaphore.

Comment: @DeZee: "*can't even find in cpp reference that over-releasing results in UB.*" It's [right here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/release). When a "precondition" is violated, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @DeZee: "*better not to pretend that binary semaphores exist - for me it's just a counting semaphore*" I don't know what that means. Binary semaphores *are* counting semaphores; just with a max of 1 instead of something larger. They're the same template type; implementations can sometimes provide more optimal implementations for the case of a maximum of 1. Releasing a binary semaphore twice is exactly as wrong in exactly the same way as releasing a counting semaphore with a maximum of 2 three times.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the precondition. There is an internal counter (which is not readable) used in the precondition definition - in my particular case, I had to use my own counter and synchronize it properly to assure that the precondition is met.
_"implementations can sometimes provide more optimal implementations for the case of a maximum of 1"_ - ok, this is a more convincing reason for binary semaphore type to be defined.
Thank you for all the answers and for clarifying my misconceptions.